# update kubernetes docker image after new image push with same or similar tag for renovate

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, renovate

I am using renovate to update my kubernetes manifest files. the process should be as follow:

- build and push docker image with tag registery.com/nginx:qa-main
- run renovate
- renovate should be able to update image tag inside the helm values.yaml

I have tried these configuration and they sometimes work and sometimes do not:

```
  # renovate.json
 {
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:base"
  ],
  "regexManagers": [
    {
      "fileMatch": ["clusters\/dev\/charts\/renovate\/values\.yaml"],
      "description": "Update docker image references",
      "matchStrings": ["image: (?<depName>.*?):(?<currentValue>.*?)@(?<currentDigest>sha256:[a-f0-9]+)s"],
      "datasourceTemplate": "docker"
    }
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchDatasources": ["docker"],
      "matchUpdateTypes": [
        "major"
      ],
      "enabled": false
    }
  ]
}


#renovate-config.js
module.exports = {
  token: 'mytoken',
  platform: 'github',
  logLevel: 'debug',
  labels: ['renovate', 'dependencies', 'automated'],
  onboarding: true,
  onboardingConfig: {
    extends: ['config:base', '":dependencyDashboard"'],
  },
  baseBranches: [],
  repositories: ['mycompany/myrepo'],
  renovateFork: true,
  gitAuthor: "mark <a.mark@mycompany.com>",
  username: "Fettah",
  onboarding: false,
  printConfig: true,
  requireConfig: false,
  logFile: "renovate.log.json",
};

# values.yaml
image: fettah/nginx:qa-main@sha256:bbd1281091831284e9488b713ee2a29b6a54494cf3519e352faa589c221c0898
```